# Why can't we initialize TrueClass in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Why can't we initialize `TrueClass` in Ruby? I get this:

```
TrueClass.new # => NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for TrueClass:Class
```

But, `superclass` of `TrueClass` is `Object`.

Similarly we are unable to initialize `NilClass` and `FalseClass`

I just wanted to know how that is possible even if that is the child class of `Object`. If we wanted to write a class similar to this how can we achieve it?

Comment: What you're trying to achive?

Comment: Just I'm curious to know how it is disabled from creating new object?

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/TrueClass.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen "The global value true is the only instance of class TrueClass". But, I wanted to know how it was stopped creating new instance for the class? Can we write our own class with that "no one can initialize it and having only one instance?" if so, how can we achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just wanted to know how that is possible even if that is the child class of Object. If we wanted to write a class similar to this how can we achieve it?

You can undefine inherited methods using the `undef` keyword. Since `new` is a class method, you'll have to use `undef` inside the class's singleton class. That would look like this:

```
class <<MyClass
  undef new
end
MyClass.new # NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for MyClass:Class
```

Answer (score 5):

> I just wanted to know how that is possible even if that is the child class of Object.

It works by undefining `allocate` and `new`. Here's the [corresponding C code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_1/object.c#L3608-L3609):

```c
rb_undef_alloc_func(rb_cTrueClass);
rb_undef_method(CLASS_OF(rb_cTrueClass), "new");
```

You can achieve a similar result in Ruby via [`undef_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-undef_method):

```
class FooClass
  ::FOO = new    # <- this will be the only Foo instance
  class << self
    undef_method :allocate
    undef_method :new
  end
end

FooClass.new      #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for FooClass:Class
FooClass.allocate #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `allocate' for FooClass:Class

FOO #=> #<FooClass:0x007fddc284c478>
```

"similar", because `TrueClass.allocate` doesn't actually raise a `NoMethodError`, but a `TypeError`:

```
TrueClass.allocate #=> TypeError: allocator undefined for TrueClass
```

Unfortunately, `rb_undef_alloc_func` is not available from within Ruby. We could mimic the behavior by overriding `allocate`:

```
class FooClass
  class << self
    def allocate
      raise TypeError, "allocator undefined for #{self}"
    end
    undef_method :new
  end
end

FooClass.allocate  #=> TypeError: allocator undefined for FooClass
```

Not sure, which approach is cleaner.

---

The above changes prevent you from creating an instance via `new`, but there are other ways:

```
FOO       #=> #<FooClass:0x007fddc284c478>

FOO.dup   #=> #<FooClass:0x007fad721122c8>
FOO.clone #=> #<FooClass:0x007f83bc157ba0>

Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(FOO)) #=> #<FooClass:0x007f83bc13e330>
```

To account for all these special cases, Ruby' stdlib provides the [`Singleton`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) module:

```
require 'singleton'

class Foo
  include Singleton
end
```

It works by making `allocate` and `new` private methods: (among [other changes](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html#module-Singleton-label-Implementation))

```
Foo.new      #=> NoMethodError: private method `new' called for Foo:Class
Foo.allocate #=> NoMethodError: private method `new' called for
```

And it adds `instance` which returns an instance: (or *the* instance, there's only one)

```
Foo.instance #=> #<Foo:0x007fdca11117e8>
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan. I understand a little bit. So, here comes my second question: Can we write a class similar to this?